# Specified number of equal rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on a medical database with oracle where I'm trying to find randomly matched samples. I have created a table with all patients and after that a table with the patients which have the illness I am looking for. Now I am wondering if it is possible to match exactly 3 randomly chosen patients to my target group (so each patient from the target group gets 3 randomly chosen patients from the table with all patients) compared on the basis of gender and year of birth.

```
SELECT A.PATIENTID
FROM   ALLPATIENTS A,
       DIAGNOSES B
WHERE  A.YEAROFBIRTH = B.YEAROFBIRTH
       AND A.GENDER = B.GENDER
       AND A.PATIENTID NOT IN (SELECT PATIENTID
                               FROM   DIAGNOSES);
```

My query is showing me all patients which have a match in the diagnoses group. That means that patients from diagnoses group with a for example more common year of birth are overrepresented. Thats why I want only 3 samples for each patient from my diagnoses group. I hope you could get an idea of what im talking about

Thanks so much

Comment: The last where condition makes me very confused, what do you mean with "A.PATIENTID NOT IN (select PATIENTID from DIAGNOSES)"?

Comment: @jarlh . . . S/he means that patients in the treatment group (`diagnoses`) cannot be in any of the cohorts.  That is `diagnoses` are separate from `allpatients`, but `allpatients` has everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! (I guess I'm still tired after the New Year celebrations...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve the problem by using weights in your analysis.  However, that is not your question.  Here is a way to get three randomly selected rows:

```
select *
from (select d.PATIENTID, p.PATIENTID,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.PATIENTID ORDER BY dbms_random.value) as seqnum 
      from ALLPATIENTS p join
           DIAGNOSES d
      where p.YEAROFBIRTH = d.YEAROFBIRTH AND
            p.GENDER = d.GENDER AND
            p.PATIENTID NOT IN (select d2.PATIENTID from DIAGNOSES d2)
     ) dp
where seqnum <= 3;
```

This enumerates all the matching rows and then randomly chooses three.  Note:  this is *with* replacement, so a patient can appear in more than one cohort.  *Without* replacement is more challenging, but possible.